# How can I have maven build a project which it generated?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project which uses the exec-maven-plugin to run [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen), which produces a a new maven project in a sub-directory. What I'd like, is for the same maven process to the go on to build the generated project.

Declaring the generated project directory as a module doesn't seem to work, I think because maven processes all the pom.xml files first, and then starts building (so the generated project doesn't exist yet when it would be needed).

I guess I could invoke a new maven process again from the exec-maven-plugin (though I'm unsure if it would be easy to find details like where the maven binary in use is, and what the goal is etc). Hopefully someone can suggest a more elegant approach.

Comment: I would use two distinct build profiles, one for submodule generation, and another - the real build, but I doubt it could be called more elegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

- The [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)
- The [Maven Invoker Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/)

Below an example of how to use the Exec Plugin in this scenario:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-module</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>mvn</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>clean</argument>
            <argument>install</argument>
        </arguments>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}\module-name</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you need different dependencies for its execution and you don't want to add them as part of your project, you can also define them as described [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html), the Exec plugin will use plugin dependencies during its execution. Make also sure to properly set the `workingDirectory` for its execution.

Although the Invoker Plugin is defined for running integration tests during a Maven plugin development, it could also suit your need in this case. Below a possible example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <pom>${basedir}/module-dir/pom.xml</pom>
        <streamLogs>true</streamLogs>
        <failIfNoProject>true</failIfNoProject>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
        </goals>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-module</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I would also suggest to check for further options of the [run](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html) goal of the Invoker Plugin.

In both approach, you should make sure to have this plugins executed after the generation phase, check the Maven [phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) flow then (i.e. if you are generating your project during the `generate-sources` phase, then the execution/build of this project could happen in the `process-resources` phase).

Comment: Thanks for the help - Invoker seemed to work, but I couldn't find any way to declare it to use the same goal as the original maven run - Ideally I'd attach it to 'process' and call 'process' if that's the goal, and use install or deploy in those cases.

I think the exec plugin would be problematic because, depending on the build machine in question, mvn may not be on the path (or in the same place), but I haven't tried it - Maybe mvn is special-cased to be the same as the existing maven process. Presumably it would suffer from the exact same 'what goal do we run' problem even then...